# Как передать два одинаковых props'a одному компоненту React?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть компонент, в который я передаю два компонента с иконкой, `label` и `input`, затем, когда я буду вызывать компонент `InputComp` в другом месте, я хочу видеть `input` с двумя разными иконками.

Как это сделать правильно?

```
export default function InputComp() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Label htmlFor="Password">
      <Icon glyph={glyph} viewBox={viewBox}/>
      <Input name="Password" placeholder="Your Password" type="password" />
      <Icon glyph={glyph} viewBox={viewBox} />
    </Label>
  </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: Передавать в `InputComp` иконки, не ?

Comment: это будет переиспользуемый компонент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает их пропсами в `InputCompglyph1` передавать?

```
<InputComp glyph1={glyph1} glyph2={glyph2}/>
```

И потом использовать:

```
export default function InputComp() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Label htmlFor="Password">
      <Icon glyph={this.props.glyph1} viewBox={viewBox}/>
      <Input name="Password" placeholder="Your Password" type="password" />
      <Icon glyph={this.props.glyph2} viewBox={viewBox} />
    </Label>
  </div>

  );
}
```

Ну или массивом:

```
<InputComp glyphs={glyphsArray}/>
```

И потом использовать:

```
export default function InputComp() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Label htmlFor="Password">
      <Icon glyph={this.props.glyphs[0]} viewBox={viewBox}/>
      <Input name="Password" placeholder="Your Password" type="password" />
      <Icon glyph={this.props.glyphs[1]} viewBox={viewBox} />
    </Label>
  </div>

  );
}
```